# Adding " before distinct value in select

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have written the select to get the distinct table name (I have to use dba_tab_cols table because it's the only one with table names I have permission:

```
select distinct(table_name)||'"'||':' as SQL_TXT from dba_tab_cols where table_name = 'SAMPLE_TABLE'
```

I would like to add " before the table_name in this select, however when I write the following:

```
select '"'||distinct(table_name) I got the error:
```

```
**00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:**
```

I could not find similar topic, that is why I am sending this question.

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distinct` is part of the `select`.  So:

```
select distinct ('"' || table_name || '"' || ':') as SQL_TXT
from dba_tab_cols
where table_name = 'SAMPLE_TABLE';
```

`select distinct` is a "single" keyword that applies to all expressions in the `select`.  It is not a function that applies to a single column.

Comment: So easy! Thanks a lot :)